# radio button values not getting stored in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, xampp

**one.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head> 
<title>page1</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>
<div id="one"> 
<form method="post" action="connect1.php">
<h4>Answer all the questions on the scale (1)Strongly agree to (5)Strongly disagree </h4>
<table width="1000" border="1" cellpadding="10">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:50% ; text-align:center" scope="col">Questions</th>
    <th style="width:10% ; text-align:center" scope="col">Strongly agree</th>
    <th style="width:10% ; text-align:center" scope="col">Agree</th>
    <th style="width:10% ; text-align:center" scope="col">Neutral</th>
    <th style="width:10% ; text-align:center" scope="col">Disagree</th>
    <th style="width:10% ; text-align:center" scope="col">Strongly disagree</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.People are clear about their role and performance levels expected of them.</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1a">
      1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1b">
      2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1c">
      3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1d">
      4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="q1e">
      5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.People understand how their role fits with the responsibilities of others.</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2a">
      1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2b">
      2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2c">
      3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2d">
      4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="q2e">
      5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3.People understand the contribution they are making to organisational objectives.</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="q3a">
      1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="q3b">
      2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="q3c">
      3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="q3d">
      4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="q3e">
      5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4.People are clear about the behaviours expected of them in achieving their objectives.</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="q4a">
      1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="q4b">
      2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="q4c">
      3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="q4d">
      4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q4" value="q4e">
      5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5.Values and attributes are aligned with each other and support critical behaviour such as customer service or innovation.</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q5" value="q5a">
      1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q5" value="q5b">
      2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q5" value="q5c">
      3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q5" value="q5d">
      4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q5" value="q5e">
      5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6.People feel the organisational systems are 'in sync' with their objectives.</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q6" value="q6a">
      1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q6" value="q6b">
      2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q6" value="q6c">
      3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q6" value="q6d">
      4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q6" value="q6e">
      5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7.People believe they are given space to try new ideas or ways of doing things.</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q7" value="q7a">
      1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q7" value="q7b">
      2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q7" value="q7c">
      3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q7" value="q7d">
      4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q7" value="q7e">
      5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8.Knowledge-sharing enables people to learn from one another.</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q8" value="q8a">
      1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q8" value="q8b">
      2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q8" value="q8c">
      3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q8" value="q8d">
      4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q8" value="q8e">
      5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9.Cross-functional working enables people to learn from others' experiences.</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q9" value="q9a">
      1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q9" value="q9b">
      2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q9" value="q9c">
      3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q9" value="q9d">
      4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q9" value="q9e">
      5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10.People watch for changes within the external world that might impact on the organisation.</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q10" value="q10a">
      1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q10" value="q10b">
      2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q10" value="q10c">
      3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q10" value="q10d">
      4</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q10" value="q10e">
      5</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**connect1.php**:

```
<?php 
//connecting to the database 
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('DB_NAME', 'survey'); 
define('DB_USER','root'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD',''); 
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

//inserting Record to the database
$q1 = $_POST['q1'];
$q2 = $_POST['q2'];
$q3 = $_POST['q3'];
$q4 = $_POST['q4'];
$q5 = $_POST['q5'];
$q6 = $_POST['q6'];
$q7 = $_POST['q7'];
$q8 = $_POST['q8'];
$q9 = $_POST['q9'];
$q10 = $_POST['q10'];
$query = "INSERT INTO one(q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9,q10)VALUES('$q1','$q2','$q3','$q4','$q5','$q6','$q7','$q8','$q9','$q10')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
if($result) 
{ 
echo "Thank you for taking the test!"; 
} 
else 
{ 
die('Error: '.mysql_error($con)); 
} 
mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

**Result in database**:

[image: only the value for first question $q1 is getting stored in the db. Remaining all nine values have value as 0 stored. What is causing this]

I have ten inputs for ten questions marked from `$q1` to `$q10`. Each question has five radio button options and user selects one. While getting stored into the database the value for `$q1` column is stored (`q1a`/`q1b`/`q1c`/`q1d`/`q1e`) as one of these five options. But for the next questions only zero (`0`) is stored.

Comment: The code highlighting should tell you you have an unclosed quoted literal somewhere

Comment: Probably here `<td>9.Cross-functional working enables people to learn from others' experiences.</td>`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nah, it was just due to bad formatting - the highlighter was confused about the language because it was all stuffed in one code block with the filenames prefixed.

Comment: I just pasted your code and works fine here.

Comment: In that case add a `print_r($_POST);` at the top of `connect1.php` and show us what it produces. **edit your question with the results, dont paste as a comment**

Comment: @BikashP can u show me your database result. Also any suggestion as to why it is not working here.

Comment: What is the data type of the fields from q2 to q10. If the values is stored as 0 probably their type is integer and you need to store string. If the type is not varchar, make it varchar.

Comment: print_r($_POST);
just add this before insert statement and see values are passing

Comment: Correct @PavelPetrov, Exactly.

Comment: I have not added it to db.i just printed it on connect1.php page and it echoed all data posted.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the result is getting printed but the db still shows value 0. this is after i added the print statement "Array ( [q1] => q1c [q2] => q2b [q3] => q3d [q4] => q4b [q5] => q5b [q6] => q6e [q7] => q7d [q8] => q8c [q9] => q9b [q10] => q10a ) Thank you for taking the test!"

Comment: I think now you should check field data type. I guess field type is int .

Comment: So what was the culprit ?

Answer (score 0):

First of, avoid the usage of mysql_ functions you should convert this to PDO with prepared statements. Examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

The reason for this is that mysql_ was deprecated from PHP5.5 and is totaly removed from PHP7. Your current code is vulnerable for both SQL injections and Cross site scripting, PDO would help you with the SQL injection issue.

You have too verify the data that comes in from the user, ALLWAYS. You can't trust them. If someone was to edit the values of the radio buttons, they can insert any thing into the database. 
When you're working with POST/GET i recomend PHP's built in input filter, filter_input() function, which will filter the input for you too prevent Cross site scripting.

You should also prevent the usage of die(); and mysql error messages should not be displayed to the end user. You should just display a text that says something happend and not the actual error, this should be logged for your eyes too read only.

Make spaces after each segment of the query, readability and formating may break your insert. INSERT INTO one (q1, q2) VALUES ('$q1', '$q2'). But this will be a little bit different if you decide to go with PDO.

Try to var_dump($_POST) to see if you have POST data on submission.

ROOT without password is also VERY critical, there should atleast be a password, using root in general is not a good practice. The best is if you can make a new user just the that database.

I hope you take this as constructive criticism, i'm just trying to make your code better and more secure.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a username and password in my system just didnt display it here. And since i am just learning to code I didnt know about deprecation of my_sql functions. Will replace my php code with the PDO functions as suggested. Will surely post any query or result after modification. Thanks a lot for your input!